# Only second audio plays JavaScript onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

I'm trying to add sound effects to my website, a positive one when they click on the correct image and a negative one when they click on the wrong image. At the moment only the negative sound gets played for both clicks, or depending on what order i put the sounds in, the positive one gets played.
This is my html:

```
<audio controls autoplay hidden id="correct">
    <source src="positive.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio controls autoplay hidden id="wrong">
    <source src="negative.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
    
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(); playPositive()"> <img src="true.png">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">CORRECT</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(); playNegative()"> <img src="false.png"
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">INCORRECT</span>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
var myMusic= document.getElementById("correct");
function playPositive() {
    myMusic.play();
}

var myMusic= document.getElementById("wrong");
function playNegative() {
    myMusic.play();
}
```

Why does it only use the second sound for both function, even when I click on right image and wrong image?

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are using the same variable name for both audio elements:

fix it like this:

```
var myCorrectMusic= document.getElementById("correct");
function playPositive() {
    myCorrectMusic.play();
}

var myWrongMusic= document.getElementById("wrong");
function playNegative() {
    myWrongMusic.play();
}
```